# AddComponent using a variable

Tags: c#, unity

I want to add a Component to a GameObject using an existing instance of the Component class.

Let's say I have the class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {
    int id {get; set;}
    string name {get; set;}
    //and other many variables
}
```

In another class I already have an instance of `Foo` with all variables setup.

What I want to do is attach the existing instance of `Foo` to a `GameObject`, instead to attach it and then setup all the variables.

Something like that, it is just an example, of course it give errors:

```
GameObject go;      //Existing GameObject
Foo foo;            //Existing instance of Foo with variables setup.  

go.AddComponent(foo);
```

Instead of doing:

```
GameObject go;      //Existing GameObject
Foo foo;            //Existing instance of Foo with variables setup.  

go.AddComponent("Foo");

Foo myComponent = go.GetComponent<Foo>();
myComponent.id = foo.id;
myComponent.name = foo.name;
//and so on
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Nah, there's no way of copying/duplicating variables from one Component to another Component via scripting that I know of. I think what you're doing with your current method is the way to go, setting the variables one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to add the existing component. However, it is possible to make it easier to duplicate the existing component into the new one:

```
Foo newFoo = go.AddComponent(foo.GetType());
foreach (FieldInfo fi in foo.GetType().GetFields())
{
  fi.SetValue(newFoo, fi.GetValue(foo));
}
```

This uses [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to copy the fields of the old component to the fields of the new component. Do note that `GetFields()` only returns fields marked as `public`. You can get everything but private fields using [binding flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Remember to update the reference at the end if you want to use `foo` to reference `go`'s `Foo` component:

```
foo = newFoo;
```

Alternatively, I'm not sure how you're creating the `foo` component in the first place, but I'd pass in the game object you want to attach.

```
public static Foo CreateFoo(ref GameObject go) {
    Foo foo = go.AddComponent<Foo>();
    //Setup foo
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: Note that reflection is [slow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/224245/382780). Also, might want to look into [Object.MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)!